# Line Divider in Android AppWidget

Tags: android, view, android-appwidget

I have a `LinearLayout` in my `AppWidget` and it loads just fine.  But when I add a line divider in between the elements within the `LinearLayout` it says "`Problem loading Widget`".  The LogCat doesn't seem to be showing any errors for it though.  Here's the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="22sp" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#EEEEEE"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#4A4A4A"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `View` as the divider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout):

> A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support
>   the following layout classes:
>
> - FrameLayout
> - LinearLayout
> - RelativeLayout
> - GridLayout
>
> and the following widget classes:
>
> - AnalogClock
> - Button
> - Chronometer
> - ImageButton
> - ImageView
> - ProgressBar
> - TextView
> - ViewFlipper
> - ListView
> - GridView
> - StackView
> - AdapterViewFlipper
>
> Descendants of these classes are not supported.

Hence, when you are trying to add a `View` to your Widget layout, your Widget will fail to load.

Learn more about widgets [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Basics).

Comment: All right thanks.  I guess I'll just use an ImageView to make the divider.  I thought that a View would be supported since it's subclasses are